# How to limit login attempts to Subversion?

Tags: security, apache-2.2, svn

We set up a Subversion server via the Apache module `mod_dav_svn` and the authentification is done via LDAP.
Now we would like to limit the login attempts to Subversion to prevent brute force attacks.
If a user (or a bot) enters its password three times wrong, he should be blocked for a specific time.

How can we establish this protection with the setup described above?

Comment: This belongs in Server Fault land I think - voting to migrate. But interesting question

Answer (score 5):

`mod_dav_svn` has an extensive [logging feature](http://www.visualsvn.com/support/svnbook/serverconfig/httpd/#svn.serverconfig.httpd.extra.logging). Combine this with [Fail2ban](http://www.fail2ban.org) and you should be able to intercept brute-force login attempts.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that in LDAP itself, if it supports the password policy IETF draft. (OpenLDAP does.) Just set the standard policy's `pwdLockout` attribute to `true`, `pwdMaxFailure` to a non-zero value, say 3 in your case, and `pwdLockoutDuration` to however many seconds you want the lockout to be, say 300, whatever you think is long enough to deter bots without annoying the hell out of real users.